# When optimizing the DWA local planner, is there a way to get the the total cost assocaited from APIs or from the parameter server?

Tags: ros, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to automate the parameter selection for DWA, for this I need to have the cost function value, is there a way to obtain this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298782/when-optimizing-the-dwa-local-planner,-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-the-total-cost-assocaited-from-apis-or-from-the-parameter-server?/) by [unrahul](https://answers.ros.org/users/36677/unrahul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

DWA does not publish the costs associated with the trajectories it selects explicitly. (You can get some of it from the `cost_cloud` topic but its indirect)

One of the motivating factors behind the way I designed [dwb_local_planner](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation) was the desire to get that information explicitly. [(slides and video here)](https://roscon.ros.org/2017/)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2